# Unzip password protected zip file and save the extracted files in Content Version record using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, contentversion, decrypt

I am working on a problem statement where we need to pick a zip folder from Files related list on Case and then Unzip it and save the pdf files back to Files on same case record. The zip folder is password protected. I am able to unzip the folder using JSZip which is a javascript library in my LWC component. Now I am trying to enhance it using some javascript to remove the password before processing it (Just FYI I am having the password save in custom metadata which i can access as per the doccument) Can anyone please suggest if this is possible to achieve in LWC ?

unzip.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="ZIP File Extractor">
     <div class="slds-flex_container">  
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium slds-flex_item">
            <lightning-button label="use jszip" onclick={handleExtract}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

unzip.js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import jszip from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/jszip";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/GetZipData.getZip';
import saveBlobData from '@salesforce/apex/GetZipData.saveBlob';


export default class ExtractZip extends LightningElement {
    
    fileBlobData
    showButton = false
    
    renderedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, jszip).then(() => {
        });
    }

    base64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
        const binaryString = atob(base64String);
        const length = binaryString.length;
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(length);
    
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          uint8Array[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    
        return uint8Array;
      }

      base64ToBlob(base64String, contentType) {
        // Convert the base64 string to binary data
        const binaryString = window.atob(base64String);
      
        // Create an ArrayBuffer with the binary data
        const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
          uint8Array[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
      
        // Create the Blob using the ArrayBuffer and content type
        return new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: contentType });
      }

      async handleExtract() {
        const contentVersionId = '069Hs00000cHuG4IAK'; // Replace this with the actual ContentVersion record Id.
    
        try {
          // Retrieve the ContentVersion record from Salesforce.
          const contentVersion = await this.getContentVersionRecord();
          console.log('1 >>>',contentVersion)
          this.fileBlobData = contentVersion;
          var zipInstance = new JSZip();
          console.log('2 >>>',zipInstance)
          const arrayBuffer = await this.base64ToUint8Array(contentVersion);
        //  this.fileBlobData = this.base64ToBlob(contentVersion,"application/zip")
          console.log('3 >>>',this.fileBlobData)
          this.showButton = true
          zipInstance.loadAsync(arrayBuffer).then(function (zip) {
            Object.keys(zip.files).forEach(function (filename) {
              zip.files[filename].async('blob').then(function (fileData) {
                 
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(fileData);
                link.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
                console.log(fileData) // These are your file contents   
                   
              })
            })
          })
       
          //console.log('3 >>>',zip)

        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error extracting ZIP archive:', error);
        }
      }
    
      // Function to retrieve the ContentVersion record from Salesforce.
      getContentVersionRecord() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            getData()
            .then((result) => {
              resolve(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              reject(error);
            });
        });
      }

      saveBlob(event){
        saveBlobData({data: this.fileBlobData})
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('blob is saved')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('error in saving blob',error)
            });
      }      
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you have done and what you want to do now? Were you able to unzip the password-protected files? What do you mean by enhancing it using some javascript to remove the password before processing it